# Drawing a circle using smoothstep() with dot() or length() produces different results

Tags: glsl, shader, smoothstep

Consider the simple shader below (head over to [shadertoy.com/new](https://www.shadertoy.com/new) and paste the code to try it out).

Basically, I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to tweak the `dot()` version to get the **exact same result** for these two function calls:

```c
smoothstep( 0.0, r * r, dot(d, d) )
smoothstep( 0.0, r,     length(d) )
```

Two circles are drawn using two well-known methods. Reading tutorials on the net, you learn that you can use the `length()` function to draw a circle. You also learn that it is quite expensive, so a more optimized version is presented where the `dot()` function is used instead. (In my world, an optimized version of something should produce the same result.)

Great. But I cannot find an explanation for the relationship between the two. Sometimes the result from `dot()` is, for some reason, multiplied by `4.0` (see [Book of Shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/07/)), giving similar but not identical output.

As you can see, `step()` yields identical circles whereas `smoothstep()` does not.

[image: Typical GLSL circles :)]

**Is it possible to get the exact same output from `smoothstep()` using some math?**

Shader example

```c
float circle_using_length(vec2 position, float radius) {
    vec2 d = position - vec2(0.5);
    return 1.0 - step(radius, length(d));
}

float circle_using_dot(in vec2 position, in float radius) {
    vec2 d = position - vec2(0.5);
    return 1.0 - step(radius * radius, dot(d, d));
}

float smooth_circle_using_length(vec2 position, float radius) {
    vec2 d = position - vec2(0.5);
    return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, radius, length(d));
}

float smooth_circle_using_dot(in vec2 position, in float radius) {
    vec2 d = position - vec2(0.5);
    return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, radius * radius, dot(d, d) /* magic needed here */);
}

void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.x;
    
    vec3 col = vec3(0.0);
    col += circle_using_length(uv + vec2(0.4, 0.05), 0.05);
    col += smooth_circle_using_length(uv + vec2(0.4, 0.2), 0.1);
    
    col += circle_using_dot(uv + vec2(0.2, 0.05), 0.05);
    col += smooth_circle_using_dot(uv + vec2(0.2, 0.2), 0.1);
    
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

Comment: You'll get the same result with `smoothstep(0.0, radius, sqrt(dot(d, d)))`. `smoothstep` is not a linear function. See [`smoothstep`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/smoothstep.xhtml). `smoothstep(0, a, b)` != `smoothstep(0, a*a, b*b)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```c
smoothstep(0.0, radius, length(d));
```

returns the same as

```c
smoothstep(0.0, radius, sqrt(dot(d, d)));
```

However it is **not equal**

```c
smoothstep(0.0, radius * radius, dot(d, d));
```

That is, because smoothstep is not a linear function and therefore `smoothstep(0, a, b)` is not equal to `smoothstep(0, a*a, b*b)`.

See [`smoothstep`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/smoothstep.xhtml):

> ```c
> t = clamp((x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0), 0.0, 1.0);
> return t * t * (3.0 - 2.0 * t);
> ```

`(a*a - 0) / (b*b - 0)` is not equal `(a - 0) / (b - 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

They're different because x<sup>2</sup> is not linear with respect to x.

Let's say that `x` is the radius of the circle. (x/2) is halfway across the circle. Well, (x/2)<sup>2</sup> is (x<sup>2</sup>)/4. This means that when the distance is halfway from the center to the edge, the `dot(d, d)` version will only act like it is one *quarter* of the way from the center to the edge.

Using the square of the distance (what you get with `dot`) is only valid if you're trying to test if a point is within a circle, not *where* it is within the circle.

Comment: So this means a smoothed circle will never look the same if we use `dot` instead of `length`?